# Determining events are independent

Tags: probability

[image]

Using the above table when we observe these three events:

Event A:  Person attended college

Event B:  Person earns less than 50,000 per year

Event C:  Person earns between 50,000 and 70,000 per year

> a. Are events A and B independent?
>
> b. Are events A and C independent?
>
> c. Are events A and B union C independent?

So for all three events I got they are independent but I want to make sure, cause even though mathematically I got that salary and college can be dependent on each other.

For all three parts I used $P(A|B)=P(A and B)/P(B)$ to show that it equals $P(A)$.  Since all three equaled each other then they are independent.  I obviously changed the events for each question but again I feel like attending college and salary can be dependent as well so I want to make sure I did the math correctly.

Here is the calculation:

a) P(A|B)=(.63)(.36)/(.36)=.63 and P(A)=.63

b) P(A|C)=(.63)(.30)/(.30)$=.63 and P(A)=.63

c) P(A|B union C)=(.63)(.66)/(.66)=.63 and P(A)=.63

Since these are all equal it means they are indp

Comment: What calculation did you explicitly perform arithmetic-wise to check that $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$?

Comment: Can you include your calculation, say in the first case?  Just optically, it sure looks like $A,B$ are dependent.

Comment: You are correct to be checking to see if $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$... but when I calculate each I definitely get that they are different values, so there must be some misunderstanding or other error on your part.  If you share with us your arithmetic and what calculation you actually performed, we will be able to help correct that.

Comment: I just added the calcuations I don't know what I did wrong..

Comment: Your calculation $\textit {assumes}$ independence.  The table gives you $P(A\cap B)$, use that value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly assumed that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)$ is true in every situation.  That is not the case.  This is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent.

The value for $P(A\cap B)$ is not meant to be calculated by multiplication of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ here (*and indeed, is never allowed to be calculated as such when you do not yet know if they are independent*), but is instead *written in the table itself*.  In the first case, the probability of simultaneously having graduated college and having a salary less than $50$k is written in the table in the second row second column entry as being $0.08$.

So, we check to see if $P(A\cap B) / P(B) = P(A)$, i.e. to see if $\frac{0.08}{0.36} = 0.63$ and we see that these are not equal, and as a result we find that $A$ and $B$ are in fact dependent events.

Comment: Awesome thanks!